# Undefined variable: /vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Save.php while save configurable product in magento2

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, sku, sku-length

When I save configurable product with big length sku then error showing

> "0":"Notice: Undefined variable: product in
>   /MASKED_DIR/2018-08-06_12-56-07/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Save.php
>   on line 156"

Answer (score 1):

I Fixed in my website!
Please check below process

1. `set "const SKU_MAX_LENGTH = 255;" in the file
   module-catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend/Sku.php`
2. You need to change the into database as well. Go to table
   `eav_attribute`, search for sku at column attribute code then edit
   the resulted row.

   Update the field `frontend_class` to null or `validate-length
   maximum-length-255` according to your requirement.
3. You have to change field size at the database table.

   `ALTER TABLE catalog_product_entity CHANGE sku sku VARCHAR(255)
   CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT
   'SKU';`

Comment: that didn't work for me :/